# Why 3 three month old baby always turns her head in an awkward position?

Tags: newborn

My 3-month-old, while lying on her back, always tries to tilt her head upwards to her right.

It looks so awkward to me.

Is it normal for a baby to do this?

Comment: Is she willing to look other directions?  Can you get her to look the other way by moving an object she is watching?  Babies *can* develop something called tortecollis, which can for sure impact head mobility.  Your doctor could easily determine if that could be an issue.  If you don't have an appointment for a check up already scheduled for soon, then you should likely schedule one sooner for an evaluation.

Comment: Just to avoid you panicking, my neice did this when she was very little and she grew out of it.

Comment: yes its totally normal.

Answer (score 4):

Young infants moving themselves into and resting in odd positions is very normal. As long as she does not seem stuck in that position it is nothing to worry about and no intervention is needed. She will gain control of her muscles and choose new more comfortable positions as she gets bigger.

My understanding is that infants will naturally move into positions similar to those which they had in the womb, however I can't find any good sources to back that explanation up.